# How do you apply a pure torque?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque, moment

A pure torque does not have a point of application. For example, in the beam shown below, the reactions are same regardless of the torque placement:

[image]

But how do you apply torque in reality?
For example if you use a screwdriver or a double force the beam deformation is different based on where you apply the torque as shown below:

[image]

Another example, how do you calculate the reaction forces in the systems shown below:

[image]

So, does pure torque exist in reality?

Comment: What is your definition of “pure torque”?

Comment: @Jbag1212 I believe the OP is referring to a force couple.

Comment: There is no pure ANYTHING.  Say you have a steel rod 1m long and you hold one end against something else.  Tap the far end.  The impluse IS NOT transmitted instantly to the other end.

Answer (score 12):

> A pure torque does not have a point of application.

This is incorrect (as you show in your second example). A better statement is

*"The location of application of a pure torque doesn't matter in certain analyses, such as when balancing moments around any point of a rigid free object."*

The qualifiers are satisfied in your first example. But the beam in your second examples isn't a rigid free object, and the point of application of the torque does happen to matter.

Comment: 1-Both first and second examples are deformable bodies. 2-When you write balance of forces to find reactions, how do you include the torque location ?

Comment: Example (1) involves an undeformable body, because you used the original geometry for the lever arm lengths. In the process, you ignored the sensitivity of the deformation to the location of torque application, as shown in example (2).

Comment: One way the location of torque application becomes apparent is in construction of the [shear and moment diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_and_moment_diagram). We often construct these by imagining a cut that splits the beam. Either the applied torque acts on the remaining segment of interest or it doesn't. In this way, the location of torque application becomes unambiguous.

Comment: I can't find any variable representing the moment location when writing balance of forces formulation or shear and moment diagrams.

Comment: Did you look at the link? The moment diagram shows the location of the couple as a discontinuity.

Answer (score 4):

> How do you apply a pure torque

A pure torque or pure moment, is referred to as a force couple, or simply a couple. It is achieved by applying two equal and opposite parallel forces of magnitude $F$ separated by a distance $d$. This produces a net torque of $Fd$ with no net force. By convention, the symbol for a force couple in statics, $M_c$ in the diagram, simply shows the moment produced by the forces and not the forces themselves.

That said, an ideal (frictionless) pin or roller support offers no torque reaction, i.e., the sum of the moments about the pin or roller is always zero. So be aware that the torque you show at the pin location in the bottom diagrams is within the beam to the left of the pin, not at the actual pin itself.  The vertical reaction force acting up at the pin opposes one of the two equal and opposite parallel forces that produce the couple. The other would be applied further to the left of the beam. What you show as torque at the pin would be free rotation of the beam in response to its distortion. See the diagram below.

Finally, it is not true that the pure torque does not have a point of application. It's just that the point of application is irrelevant when determining the requirements for static equilibrium.  For that reason, a couple is referred to as a "free moment vector", as I explained in my answer to you previous post. On the other hand, the point of application must be taken into consideration when determining bending moments and stresses and their locations in deformable solids.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: *"A pin and roller support offers no torque reaction"* But a beam connected to that support and to another support elsewhere does. The resulting exaggerated shape is shown in the bottom panel above. If there were no torque reaction, the beam would spin.

Comment: I'm saying the net torque at an ideal pin or roller must be zero. That does not preclude bending stress within the beam everywhere between the supports.

Comment: Let's assume that it's near the support but not exactly at the pin.

Comment: @user355019 that’s what I’m showing you in my diagram

Comment: I added a new figure, please take a look.

Comment: @user355019 I don’t understand the point of the new diagram. It’s no different than the one above it

Comment: The moment i show at the pin location is NOT within the beam to the left of the pin but exactly on the pin.

Comment: @user355019 There can't be a moment about an ideal (frictionless) pin. That's why when we do static equilibrium requirements for beams we always take the sum of the moments about a pin equal to be zero.

Comment: There can be a moment about an ideal pin as I showed in the figure but the moment is not transferred to the support. The sum of moments around this point can still be zero.

Comment: I'm saying there cannot be a NET moment about an ideal hinge.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with my question. Im asking if the reaction forced are similar in both cases.

Comment: @user355019 The reaction forces have nothing to do with where the couple is located because the net force associated with a couple is always zero, no matter where the couple is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the heart of this paradox is that "pure torque" is in idealization (as is "rigid body")  in fact "pure torques" do not exist (anything applying a torque applies finite forces at points that have a finite distance apart).  What we are seeing with the latter example is that the idea of applying torque at a point is useful only to the degree that the rigid body approximation (e.g. r_ij is fixed for all the elements comprising the body) is valid.

If the body can deform, then how it deforms is determined by where the forces act.  You need to work with pressures and stress on the object in order to determine how it deforms (e.g. a hex nut that is stripped will not deform the same way as a phillips screw because the stresses on the object are different)